# Expanding and Compressing Tabs in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

How would you implement in Common Lisp a solution to the problem [Expanding and Compressing Tabs](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch01_08.htm) in Perl Cookbook ?

I want to convert tabs in a string to the appropriate number of spaces, or vice versa.

Is there a known package for this ?

Comment: [Common Lisp Cookbok: Strings](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/strings.html) or [Regular expression library](http://www.cliki.net/regular%20expression)

Comment: Common Lisp Cookbook does not have this recipe, that's why I'm asking it here.

Comment: For expansion, you might be able to start with `(format nil (cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all "\\t" str "~1,8@T"))`.